# Is there a way to test webGL renderings with Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webgl

I am using webdriver to navigate a web app which then has WebGl renderings.  I can grab a screenshot and try to do image compare, but is there a better way to verify renderings?
One of the problems is that the rendering can have pulsing or otherwise changing icons, which makes image compare problematic.

Comment: Have you tried image comparison and stuck at point where images are pulsating or icons changing? if yes please share your code. That way you will have a better chance of a helpful answer.

Comment: You generally need to find a way to get the page into a stable state, wait for animations to stop or manually stop them or pass in some argument to turn them off, then take the screenshot. Also be aware different GPUs do internal computations like varyings and bilinear filtering slightly different so you won't be able to compare across GPUs unless you make carefully constructed tests that don't use those features that express differently per GPU